# What's the probability of creating a Hello World Program?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random

Consider an application that has knowledge of all characters on the keyboard i.e. if asked to do so it can randomly choose any character and output it.

Now, in the programming language Java consider the simple code below:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

All it does is to print out Hello World. The code to compile the program requires 96 characters including spaces and should be exactly as above. For this example we are going to assume that there are 95 different characters which can be represented by the standard keyboard.

Now, if I instructed my application to choose 96 random characters, what is the probability that it would result in a hello world program ? only Hello World is acceptable not HELLO WORLD etc.

If it takes Java on average 0.2 seconds to compile code of length 96 characters and there is 0.2 seconds between each attempt how long would the worst case scenario take before succeeding ?

It's not infinite is it?

I considered for a long time where to post this question and seeing as the main approach here is to use maths I thought I would try here.

Comment: If you want exactly this code (and not an equivalent program that would print Hello World), and you take characters from the 96 printable ASCII chars (32-127 + newline), you have probability $1 \over 96^{96}$, which is quite small. In the worst case scenario, you never succeed, of course. But you can expect to find one every $96^{96}$ attempts.

Comment: @arbautjc I think that the printable characters total $ 127 - 32 $, plus up to two for newlines (since Windows uses `\r\n`), so you'd have $ \frac{1}{96^{127-32+2}} $, not $ \frac{1}{96^{128}} $.

Comment: Oups, you're right there was a mistake in my answer! For CRLF, that depends, if you're on Linux it's only LF ;-)

Comment: No, indeed. And it's even less probable that you will succeed using a random number generator, which is not really random (thus not all combinations of letters are guaranteed to appear).

Comment: @Jatt You can have more or less any amount of whitespace between keywords like `public`, `class`, etc., so it's somewhat larger, but not significantly so. Though you could try another language — as the joke goes, “I once piped `/dev/random` into Perl and got a web server”.

Comment: You wont necessarily find something every 1/p attempts if it has probability p.

Comment: However, there are an infinite amount of programs that would output Hello World, not just this one. Hmm....I have a feeling this would be easier to calculate in a more mathematically defined language like Scheme.